# Run CI command as non-root using su

Tags: bash, su

Our CI servers use docker images that are all running as root.
Now I have a Maven build that can't run as root, so I'm trying to build this wrapper script for creating a user, copying the Maven settings from root, and then running a script.

Here's what I have

```
#! /bin/bash -ex

useradd -m nonroot
cp -R /root/.m2 /home/nonroot/.m2
chown -R nonroot /home/nonroot/.m2
su nonroot -c "$@"
```

The problem is: when I call this script as `./nonroot.sh mvn clean install`, it only executes `mvn`, not `mvn clean install`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Note, you can use `sudo -u nonroot` to run commands usually, but if you need to use `su` here's a way to pass the command and args without losing spaces and so on:

```
su nonroot -c '"$@"' dummy "$@"
```

This takes advantage of the way bash accepts args after `-c` and uses them to set `$1` etc. Eg:

```
bash -c 'echo $*' 1 2 3
```

results in the output `2 3`, as the first arg is taken as the program name. So we make bash run the command `"$@"`, then pass the real arguments.

Comment: sudo is not installed on my container, forgot to mention that, sorry

Comment: wow, that's black magic. will look into it, thanks